# What options are picked when I use multiple nested SWRConfig?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I am currently using SWRConfig for having a global fetcher, but I also want to overwrite this fetcher in some components, would the upper level SWRConfig options be used?

```
<SWRConfig
    value={{
      fetcher: (resource, init) =>
        fetch(resource, init).then((res) => res.json()),
    }}
  >
       ...
         <SWRConfig
             value={{
               fetcher: customFetch
            }}
          >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `SWRConfig` configurations will be extended. For your scenario, it means if you call `useSWR` inside the second `SWRConfig` it will use the fetcher defined there (`customFetch`).

Alternatively, you can also define the fetcher on the `useSWR` call directly to override the global one at any point.

```js
useSWR('my-key', customFetch)
```